# Mongodb query returns complex data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When querying a simple mongodb collection (nodejs / mongoose), It returns a complex array of objects. It contains information about the model, internalcache, etc:

```
  model {
    '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: {},
      shardval: undefined,
      saveError: undefined,
      validationError: undefined,
      adhocPaths: undefined,
      removing: undefined,
      inserting: undefined,
      version: undefined,
      getters: {},
      _id: 5e4013b9d0743949edf64ac9,
      populate: undefined,
      populated: undefined,
      wasPopulated: false,
      scope: undefined,
      activePaths: [StateMachine],
      pathsToScopes: {},
      ownerDocument: undefined,
      fullPath: undefined,
      emitter: [EventEmitter],
      '$options': true
    },
    isNew: false,
    errors: undefined,
    _doc: {
      tags: [Array],
      date: 2020-02-09T14:14:17.258Z,
      _id: 5e4013b9d0743949edf64ac9,
      name: 'Dummy name',
      creator: 'John',
      active: true,
      __v: 0
  },
```

I expected just to get an array with the objects stored in the db (assigned to the _doc property in my results). How can I make Mongodb return only these objects like this:

```
[{
   tags: [Array],
   date: 2020-02-09T14:14:17.258Z,
   _id: 5e4013b9d0743949edf64ac9,
   name: 'Dummy name',
   creator: 'John',
   active: true,
   __v: 0
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `.lean()` to your query to get only a JSON-Object version of the result. See an example here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById